# show modal after accepting cookie while close and reopen browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have implemented the below functionality to accept cookie modal on my site. If I accept, it is working properly modal not showing on refresh or opening site in a new tab until I close the browser. If I close and reopen the browser then the open site accepts cookie modal showing again.

I have added below code for that,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cookieModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="notice d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="cookie-text">This website uses cookies to personalize content and analyse traffic in
                            order to offer you a better experience.</div>
                        <div class="buttons d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-blue mr-2 accept-cookies"
                                data-dismiss="modal">Accept</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-blue mr-2 close-cookies"
                                data-dismiss="modal">Reject</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



if (document.cookie.indexOf("accepted_cookies=") < 0) {​​​​​​​
    $('#cookieModal').modal('show');
}​​​​​​​


$('.accept-cookies').on('click', function () {​​​​​​​
    document.cookie = "accepted_cookies=yes;"
    $('#cookieModal').modal('hide');
}​​​​​​​)


$('.close-cookies').on('click', function () {​​​​​​​
    $('#cookieModal').modal('hide');
}​​​​​​​)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you don't set the `expire` of a cookie, it will be `session` by default. So when you close and reopen the browser it will be throw away.

In order to set an expiration date you can use the following code:

```
const now = new Date()
const currentTime = now.getTime()
const expireTime = currentTime + 1000 * 60 * 60; // one hour
now.setTime(expireTime)
document.cookie = 'accepted_cookies=yes;expires='+now.toUTCString()+';';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to implement the same code and it is working correctly until the machine is not shut down.

Once I shut down and re-start my machine and open the site then the modal pop-up showing again even I have accepted cookies.